# Reading a row-wise and stanza formatted text file in Pandas

Tags: pandas, text-files

I am used to the flexibility of `pandas.read_csv` for most of my text-file reading needs. I have come across a text file that I would like to read as-is (without pre-processing) with `Pandas` or a similar (common) `Python` library like `numpy`. The data file contains a significant amount of metadata and ancillary information interspersed with stanzas like this:

```
  Neutron Multigroup Structure (MeV)
  0.000E+00 1.000E-01 2.000E-01 3.000E-01 4.000E-01 5.000E-01 6.000E-01 7.000E-01
  8.000E-01 9.000E-01 1.000E+00 1.100E+00 1.200E+00 1.300E+00 1.400E+00 1.500E+00
  1.600E+00 1.700E+00 1.800E+00 1.900E+00 2.000E+00 2.100E+00 2.200E+00 2.300E+00
  2.400E+00 2.500E+00 2.600E+00 2.700E+00 2.800E+00 2.900E+00 3.000E+00 3.100E+00
  3.200E+00 3.300E+00 3.400E+00 3.500E+00 3.600E+00 3.700E+00 3.800E+00 3.900E+00
  4.000E+00 4.100E+00 4.200E+00 4.300E+00 4.400E+00 4.500E+00 4.600E+00 4.700E+00
  4.800E+00 4.900E+00 5.000E+00 5.100E+00 5.200E+00 5.300E+00 5.400E+00 5.500E+00
  5.600E+00 5.700E+00 5.800E+00 5.900E+00 6.000E+00 6.100E+00 6.200E+00 6.300E+00
  6.400E+00 6.500E+00 6.600E+00 6.700E+00 6.800E+00 6.900E+00 7.000E+00 7.100E+00
  7.200E+00 7.300E+00 7.400E+00 7.500E+00 7.600E+00 7.700E+00 7.800E+00 7.900E+00
  8.000E+00 8.100E+00 8.200E+00 8.300E+00 8.400E+00 8.500E+00 8.600E+00 8.700E+00
  8.800E+00 8.900E+00 9.000E+00 9.100E+00 9.200E+00 9.300E+00 9.400E+00 9.500E+00
  9.600E+00 9.700E+00 9.800E+00 9.900E+00 1.000E+01

  (a,n) neutrons/sec-cc from  6.34600E+14 at/cc th232  alphas on  c 13  in target
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 9.909E-21 3.824E-20 5.810E-20 7.835E-20
  1.244E-19 2.513E-19 5.399E-19 8.401E-19 1.538E-18 3.981E-18 1.037E-17 1.982E-17
  2.527E-17 3.057E-17 3.425E-17 3.913E-17 4.854E-17 5.352E-17 5.565E-17 5.735E-17
  5.695E-17 5.600E-17 5.390E-17 5.064E-17 4.591E-17 4.031E-17 3.613E-17 3.383E-17
  3.096E-17 2.781E-17 2.548E-17 2.390E-17 2.110E-17 1.789E-17 1.204E-17 6.368E-18
  4.483E-18 4.014E-18 2.073E-18 3.178E-19 6.641E-20 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
  0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
                               Total (all groups):  9.321E-16 neutrons/sec-cm**3   .
                           Average Neutron Energy:  4.199E+00 MeV.

 Total Neutron Spectrum
 5.284E-15 8.165E-15 1.001E-14 1.053E-14 1.271E-14 1.445E-14 1.436E-14 1.360E-14
 1.250E-14 1.133E-14 1.120E-14 1.306E-14 1.612E-14 2.019E-14 3.116E-14 4.400E-14
 5.012E-14 5.146E-14 5.383E-14 5.246E-14 4.523E-14 3.698E-14 3.046E-14 2.524E-14
 2.155E-14 1.751E-14 1.287E-14 9.724E-15 7.938E-15 4.896E-15 2.485E-15 2.198E-15
 2.208E-15 2.245E-15 2.281E-15 2.324E-15 2.339E-15 2.132E-15 1.862E-15 1.664E-15
 1.532E-15 1.360E-15 1.166E-15 9.751E-16 7.875E-16 6.162E-16 4.119E-16 2.049E-16
 1.665E-16 1.885E-16 2.265E-16 2.825E-16 3.390E-16 3.380E-16 3.248E-16 3.110E-16
 3.000E-16 2.890E-16 2.748E-16 2.580E-16 2.382E-16 2.132E-16 1.808E-16 1.405E-16
 9.085E-17 3.410E-17 1.025E-17 9.147E-18 8.160E-18 7.277E-18 6.486E-18 5.780E-18
 5.148E-18 4.585E-18 4.080E-18 3.631E-18 3.228E-18 2.872E-18 2.552E-18 2.268E-18
 2.014E-18 1.789E-18 1.588E-18 1.409E-18 1.251E-18 1.109E-18 9.838E-19 8.725E-19
 7.719E-19 6.848E-19 6.067E-19 5.370E-19 4.762E-19 4.202E-19 3.731E-19 3.287E-19
 2.922E-19 2.578E-19 2.271E-19 2.012E-19
                               Total (all groups):  7.020E-13 neutrons/sec-cm**3   .
                           Average Neutron Energy:  1.780E+00 MeV.
```

I want to read each of the stanzas (there are more than one) to columns in my final data structure. Within each of the number stanzas the next element is space separated but at the end of a line the structure continues on the next line. I would also like to retain some of the meta information somehow in my output data structure; for example the Average or Total numbers at the bottom of the above stanza.

EDIT:
Note each data stanza that is encountered should result in a single column of data in the `Pandas` output. Because of the input structure, every stanza has the same number of entries so when taken together all columns would be sort of like a collection of columns (variables) with the same length. The expected output for the above would be something like:

```
 Neut. Mult. Energy.     (a,n) from..     Total Neutron Spectrum
 0.000E+00                0.000E+00       5.254E-15
 1.000E-01                0.000E+00       8.165E-15
 ...                      ...             ...
```

Is there a way to configure out how to do the above in `Pandas` or another `Python` library?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your ignore how should look like your output but here is a good start :

```
import re
from io import StringIO
​
with open("file.txt") as f:
    dfs = {
        m.group(1): pd.read_fwf(StringIO(m.group(2)), header=None)
        for m in re.finditer(r"^(.+?)\n(.*?)\n\s+(.*)",
                             f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)
    }
```

*NB : `dfs` is a dictionnary where the keys are the header/title (i.e, `m.group(1)`) of the blocs/tables and the values are a pandas DataFrame.   The footer is also captured with regex (i.e, `m.group(3)`).*

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/uJ1keu/1)]

Output :

```
print(dfs["Total Neutron Spectrum"])

              0             1   ...            10            11
0   5.284000e-15  8.165000e-15  ...  1.120000e-14  1.306000e-14
1   1.612000e-14  2.019000e-14  ...  3.046000e-14  2.524000e-14
2   2.155000e-14  1.751000e-14  ...  2.281000e-15  2.324000e-15
..           ...           ...  ...           ...           ...
6   5.148000e-18  4.585000e-18  ...  1.588000e-18  1.409000e-18
7   1.251000e-18  1.109000e-18  ...  3.731000e-19  3.287000e-19
8   2.922000e-19  2.578000e-19  ...           NaN           NaN

[9 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to specify that each full stanza should represent one single column in the output.

Comment: Thanks but can you show an explicit expected output that matches the given input ?

Comment: Ok, I did an example. Added a couple more stanzas to the input for generality.